# Get Lookup table value via REST

Tags: rest, custom-field-types, project-server

I've got a project server app in which I hava a custom field that gets populated through a lookup table I've previously filled.

What I want is to get the value of this custom field using the REST API.

I've been able to get the custom field using:

```
_api/projectserver/Projects('GUID_Project')/CustomFields('GUID_CustomField')
```

and its lookupentries using:

```
_api/projectserver/Projects('GUID_Project')/CustomFields('GUID_CustomField')/LookupEntries
```

But I must be missing something because I can't find the way to link the custom field with its value.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via the query

```
_api/ProjectServer/Projects('GUID_Project')/CustomFields('GUID_CustomField')
```

you can achieve only the definitions of the custom fields, but not their value.

To get the value, we need first the internal name of the field

```
_api/ProjectServer/Projects('GUID_Project')/CustomFields('GUID_CustomField')?$select=InternalName
```

For example, if the field ID is `203ee722-6449-e411-80dd-005056b44e32`, the internal name will be `Custom_203ee7226449e41180dd005056b44e32`.

Next, get the all the the custom field values:

```
_api/ProjectServer/Projects('GUID_Project')/IncludeCustomFields
```

or only the one you need:

```
_api/ProjectServer/Projects('GUID_Project')/IncludeCustomFields?$select='InternalName_CustomField'
```

The value will be displayed as `Entry_d13ce7226449e41180dd005056b44e32`, that means lookup table entry ID `d13ce722-6449-e411-80dd-005056b44e32`.

To get the lookup table entry:

```
_api/ProjectServer/LookupTables('GUID_LookupTable')/Entries('GUID_LookupTableEntry')
```

or just its value:

```
_api/ProjectServer/LookupTables('GUID_LookupTable')/Entries('GUID_LookupTableEntry')?$select=FullValue
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the custom field value, you can use the [ProjectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163015.aspx) service:

```
http://server/pwa/_api/projectdata/Projects(guid'GUID_Project')
```

That retrieves all the project properties, including all custom field values. You can use $select to retrieve only the properties you want:

```
http://server/pwa/_api/projectdata/Projects(guid'GUID_Project')?$select=CustomFieldName1,...,CustomFieldNameN
```

A few caveats:

- The custom field name is not the name you give in the UI when creating the field. A simple way to get the name is to request the URL without the $select and look for the name in the response.
- You may use browsers to test the URL response but some kind of REST client makes things smoother. I use [Advanced Rest Client for Chrome](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwif5tCK-5zTAhVDWpAKHSD5AiYQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&bvm=bv.152180690,d.Y2I) and [HttpRequester for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/httprequester/).
- The default response format is XML; you can get JSON by specifiying "application/json;odata=verbose" in the Accept header (just "application/json" will not work).
- If you have a localized Project Server the "/Projects" segment of the URL will be localized too: my Project Server is PT-BR and the URL is `http://server/pwa/_api/projectdata/Projetos(...)`. You can get the "entity sets" names by going to the address `http://server/pwa/_api/projectdata/`.